# Is Brasilia a weak starting investment in Imperial 2030?

Tags: imperial-2030

The other day I was playing said game, and I draw Brasilia as my starting investment. While I don't feel I played particularly well, I did find it harder than the others to expand my empire. Further more, they told me that the last time someone had had Brasilia they also suffered.

Is this common in games? And if so how can I turn Brasilia's weaknesses into my strengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to link below, some people think that Brazil is a good place to start investments (in a poll with 26 votes titled "[And where do you put your money in the future?](http://www.rpggeek.com/geeklist/66752/round-1-top-100-relegationpromotion-battle-poll-c)", 50% people choose Brazil). Joe Wyka user thinks Brazil is well positoned on board...

[Rpggeek - Berkeley board gamers games played tuesday june 7 2011 - Imperial 2030](http://www.rpggeek.com/geeklist/68428/berkeley-board-gamers-games-played-tuesday-june-7)
[Rpggeek - Best new boardgames - Imperial 2030](http://www.rpggeek.com/geeklist/66853/item/1659970#item1659970)

A quote from there:

> [...]This was a weird game. I don't quite remember how things started out,
>   but Adam was trying for a US/Brazil combo, and the rest of us were
>   kinda spread around. For the first half of the game things went pretty
>   slowly, but we all had a decent cash flow - countries weren't taxing
>   for very much, but just enough that we were able to reinvest, and the
>   countries were fairly balanced. India was looking good but fragile for
>   a while, everyone was in Brazil, which was doing well (as usual) [...]
>   Eventually though after a series
>   of close Investor actions everyone except me had a big wad of cash,
>   most of which ended up in Brazil. India and Brazil started moving up
>   the power track fairly quickly (due to cross investments by Charles
>   and Garrett, their owners), while China harassed the US (which was
>   unable to slow Brazil) and Europe and Russia fought. Charles and
>   Garrett had huge investments, Charles in India/Brazil, and Garrett in
>   Russia/India/Brazil. I had a decent spread across all countries except
>   China, and Adam was mostly in Brazil/US/Europe. The game ended
>   semi-unexpectedly when Brazil jumped to tax to just make it to 25.
>   Final scores:
>
> Brazil 5x India 4x US 2x China 2x Russia 2x Europe 2x
>
> Garrett 205 Charles 186 Deniz 144 Adam 129
>
> If Charles hadn't ended it right then, Europe and Russia would have
>   each jumped up to 4x, which would have put me in a better position but
>   would also have put Garrett even further into the lead. I was hoping
>   all the countries would level out at about 4x, given how slowly it was
>   going (I had about ~7 interest in non-Chinese countries), but those
>   who were big in India and Brazil only (Charles and Garrett) won out.

Comment: This is probably the best answer I'm going to get on this.